# PHP Script for Calculating with JSON

Tags: php, arrays, var

I get an ID from MySQL and the $ id runs a specific URL that contains the $ id.

```
$Ortungsnummer = $row['Ortungs_Identifikation'];
                        
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.profi-ortung.de/api/v1/user/devices/?access_token=');

$arr = json_decode($json,true);

$arr=json_decode($json);
    
    
foreach($arr as $obj) {
    $device_id = $obj->device_id;
    $latest_signal_id = $obj->latest_signal_id;
    if ($device_id == $Ortungsnummer) {

    }
}
                        
                        
                        
$ip= "$Ortungsnummer";
$signal = "$latest_signal_id";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.profi-ortung.de/api/v1/device/$ip/signal/$signal/?access_token=");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$outputJson = curl_exec($ch);
$arr2 = json_decode($outputJson);  

                        
$fahrzeug_lat= "$arr2->dec_lat";
$fahrzeug_long= "$arr2->dec_long";
$start_lat ="52.2";
$start_long = "8.9";
                        


function distanceCalculation($point1_lat, $point1_long, $point2_lat, $point2_long, $unit = 'km', $decimals = 2) {
    
    $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat))*sin(deg2rad($point2_lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point2_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point1_long-$point2_long)))));

    
    switch($unit) {
        case 'km':
            $distance = $degrees * 111.13384; 
        case 'mi':
            $distance = $degrees * 69.05482; 
            break;
        case 'nmi':
            $distance =  $degrees * 59.97662; nautical miles)
    }
    return round($distance, $decimals);
}
                        
$point1 = array("lat" => $fahrzeug_lat, "long" => $fahrzeug_long); 
$point2 = array("lat" => $start_lat, "long" => $start_long);

$km = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);
$mi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'mi'); 
$nmi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'nmi');

echo $km;
```

When i echo it i get the data for how many $id there are! Up to here the code works!
Now I want to run an Code that calculates the distance.

The Problem is that it calculates the distance only for the first Result, so only for the first $id but `$fahrzeug_lat= "$arr2->dec_lat";` and `$fahrzeug_long= "$arr2->dec_long";` has both data in it.

I don't know how to solve the problem, please help!

Sample Data for $JSON:

```
[
    {
        "is_disable": false,
        "canbus_id": "",
        "daily_mileage": "124.67",
        "command_internal_number": "",
        "tank_height": "0",
        "immobilizer_status": 0,
        "garmin_check_driver": 0,
        "velocity_info": 0,
        "latest_mileage": "239076.8264",
        "temp_min": 0,
        "sim_number": "89490200001222280318",
        "canbus_serial": "",
        "deleted_at": "None",
        "sap_status": 1,
        "user_id": 152620,
        "latest_engine_hour": 0,
        "tank_capacity": null,
        "temp_max": 0,
        "gsm_number": "76140169",
        "beacon_id": 357454070966716,
        "note": "",
        "canbus_program_nr": "",
        "activation": 0,
        "car_state": "",
        "serial_number": "07224812",
        "type": 75,
        "price": "13.90",
        "added_by": 30,
        "latest_signal_id": 11375391888,
        "gsm_areacode": "0151",
        "tank_capacity_lt": 0,
        "latest_zone_id": -1,
        "hide_status": false,
        "latest_geofence_signal_id": 11375383116,
        "trip_status": 0,
        "added_at": "2016-08-11 17:12:48",
        "device_id": 1000016558,
        "name": "100",
        "transmission": "94.5746676141",
        "box_type": 22,
        "start_date": "None",
        "latest_task_record_id": 0,
        "command_password": "",
        "canbus_type": "",
        "latest_geocode_sent_at": "2020-07-09 15:52:40"
    },
    {
        "is_disable": false,
        "canbus_id": "",
        "daily_mileage": "233.28",
        "command_internal_number": "",
        "tank_height": "0",
        "immobilizer_status": 0,
        "garmin_check_driver": 0,
        "velocity_info": 0,
        "latest_mileage": "226282.657",
        "temp_min": 0,
        "sim_number": "89490200001222287305",
        "canbus_serial": "",
        "deleted_at": "None",
        "sap_status": 1,
        "user_id": 152620,
        "latest_engine_hour": 0,
        "tank_capacity": null,
        "temp_max": 0,
        "gsm_number": "76098470",
        "beacon_id": 356173068452528,
        "note": "",
        "canbus_program_nr": "",
        "activation": 0,
        "car_state": "",
        "serial_number": "06652243",
        "type": 120,
        "price": "13.90",
        "added_by": 30,
        "latest_signal_id": 11375392298,
        "gsm_areacode": "0151",
        "tank_capacity_lt": 0,
        "latest_zone_id": -1,
        "hide_status": false,
        "latest_geofence_signal_id": 11375379385,
        "trip_status": 0,
        "added_at": "2016-07-18 13:17:22",
        "device_id": 1000014684,
        "name": "101",
        "transmission": "104.879623019",
        "box_type": 22,
        "start_date": "None",
        "latest_task_record_id": 0,
        "command_password": "",
        "canbus_type": "",
        "latest_geocode_sent_at": "2020-07-09 15:52:43"
    }
]
```

Sample Data for $JSON2:

```
{"canbus_engine_temp": "", "signal_id": 11375391888, "input_2_voltage": 0.0, "canbus_doors": "", "nr_sat": 18, "signal_strenght": 18, "canbus_fuel_consumption": "", "beacon_id": 357454070966716, "input_6": 0, "input_7": 0, "input_4": 0, "input_5": 0, "input_2": 0, "input_3": 0, "input_0": 0, "input_1": 1, "canbus_total_driving_time": "", "dec_long": 8.9, "canbus_fuel_level_pr": "", "mileage": 239076.8281, "canbus_lights": "", "canbus_device_state": "", "canbus_total_engine_hours": "", "canbus_fuel_level_lt": "", "canbus_total_fuel_used": "", "dec_lat": 52.3, "input_1_voltage": 14.02, "speed_km": 45.0, "canbus_info_indicators": "", "geocode_sent_at": "2020/07/09 15:52:40", "added_at": "2020-07-09 15:52:43", "signal_mode": 0, "canbus_fuel_range": "", "canbus_total_idle_fuel_use": "", "signal_type": 5, "canbus_engine_rpm": ""}
```

or

```
{"canbus_engine_temp": "", "signal_id": 11375268853, "input_2_voltage": 0.0, "canbus_doors": "", "nr_sat": 17, "signal_strenght": 18, "canbus_fuel_consumption": "", "beacon_id": 356173068452528, "input_6": 0, "input_7": 0, "input_4": 0, "input_5": 0, "input_2": 0, "input_3": 0, "input_0": 0, "input_1": 1, "canbus_total_driving_time": "", "dec_long": 9.0, "canbus_fuel_level_pr": "", "mileage": 226267.2188, "canbus_lights": "", "canbus_device_state": "", "canbus_total_engine_hours": "", "canbus_fuel_level_lt": "", "canbus_total_fuel_used": "", "dec_lat": 52.2, "input_1_voltage": 13.95, "speed_km": 10.0, "canbus_info_indicators": "", "geocode_sent_at": "2020/07/09 15:36:16", "added_at": "2020-07-09 15:36:23", "signal_mode": 0, "canbus_fuel_range": "", "canbus_total_idle_fuel_use": "", "signal_type": 5, "canbus_engine_rpm": ""}
```

Ortungsnummer for first $JSON2

```
1000014684
```

Ortungsnummer for second $JSON2

```
1000016558
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217575/discussion-on-question-by-fynn-php-script-for-calculating-with-json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```php
<?php

$sample_json = '[{
        "canbus_engine_temp": "",
        "signal_id": 11375391888,
        "input_2_voltage": 0.0,
        "canbus_doors": "",
        "nr_sat": 18,
        "signal_strenght": 18,
        "canbus_fuel_consumption": "",
        "beacon_id": 357454070966716,
        "input_6": 0,
        "input_7": 0,
        "input_4": 0,
        "input_5": 0,
        "input_2": 0,
        "input_3": 0,
        "input_0": 0,
        "input_1": 1,
        "canbus_total_driving_time": "",
        "dec_long": 8.9,
        "canbus_fuel_level_pr": "",
        "mileage": 239076.8281,
        "canbus_lights": "",
        "canbus_device_state": "",
        "canbus_total_engine_hours": "",
        "canbus_fuel_level_lt": "",
        "canbus_total_fuel_used": "",
        "dec_lat": 52.3,
        "input_1_voltage": 14.02,
        "speed_km": 45.0,
        "canbus_info_indicators": "",
        "geocode_sent_at": "2020/07/09 15:52:40",
        "added_at": "2020-07-09 15:52:43",
        "signal_mode": 0,
        "canbus_fuel_range": "",
        "canbus_total_idle_fuel_use": "",
        "signal_type": 5,
        "canbus_engine_rpm": ""
    },
    {
        "canbus_engine_temp": "",
        "signal_id": 11375268853,
        "input_2_voltage": 0.0,
        "canbus_doors": "",
        "nr_sat": 17,
        "signal_strenght": 18,
        "canbus_fuel_consumption": "",
        "beacon_id": 356173068452528,
        "input_6": 0,
        "input_7": 0,
        "input_4": 0,
        "input_5": 0,
        "input_2": 0,
        "input_3": 0,
        "input_0": 0,
        "input_1": 1,
        "canbus_total_driving_time": "",
        "dec_long": 9.0,
        "canbus_fuel_level_pr": "",
        "mileage": 226267.2188,
        "canbus_lights": "",
        "canbus_device_state": "",
        "canbus_total_engine_hours": "",
        "canbus_fuel_level_lt": "",
        "canbus_total_fuel_used": "",
        "dec_lat": 52.2,
        "input_1_voltage": 13.95,
        "speed_km": 10.0,
        "canbus_info_indicators": "",
        "geocode_sent_at": "2020/07/09 15:36:16",
        "added_at": "2020-07-09 15:36:23",
        "signal_mode": 0,
        "canbus_fuel_range": "",
        "canbus_total_idle_fuel_use": "",
        "signal_type": 5,
        "canbus_engine_rpm": ""
    }
]';
//print_r(json_decode($sample_json));

function distanceCalculation($point1_lat, $point1_long, $point2_lat, $point2_long, $unit = 'km', $decimals = 2) {
    
    $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat))*sin(deg2rad($point2_lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point2_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point1_long-$point2_long)))));

    
    switch($unit) {
        case 'km':
            $distance = $degrees * 111.13384; 
        case 'mi':
            $distance = $degrees * 69.05482; 
            break;
        case 'nmi':
            $distance =  $degrees * 59.97662;
    }
    return round($distance, $decimals);
}

$sample_array = json_decode($sample_json);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sample_array);$i++){
    

$fahrzeug_lat= $sample_array[$i]->dec_lat;
$fahrzeug_long= $sample_array[$i]->dec_long;
$start_lat ="52.2";
$start_long = "8.9";
                        
$point1 = array("lat" => $fahrzeug_lat, "long" => $fahrzeug_long); 
$point2 = array("lat" => $start_lat, "long" => $start_long);

$km = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);
$mi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'mi'); 
$nmi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'nmi');

echo $i.". KM: ".$km; echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello the code above works fine! But from each single url i get for example of Sample Data for $JSON2 the second url gave it with other value! So that the code is not working with the $sample_array[$i]->dec_lat;

Comment: you can check output. what is issue exact ?

Comment: If i insert the code path from the above code, i get this output: 0. KM: 4.39. the result is correct but it only calculates the first distance.

Comment: if i get the data from curl each $sample_json in your code is different and they are not together in one $sample_json!

Comment: what is output of sample json ? curl request you have to do inside for loop of your `foreach($arr as $obj) {` here. it will iterate twice based.

Comment: curl request is inside foreach and the outpout of sample json is for the first url this "Sample Data for $JSON2:" and for the second url "below or"

Comment: I have send you an request!